# The Load Event of the user control to occur every time.. When the user Enters the user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I Have a User Control, The load Event of this User Control is occurs Only one time,
 I want that Load event to Occur Every time When the User Enters The UserControl..

Comment: silverlight? asp? winforms? wpf? console?

Answer (score 0):

Focus is the event that would be triggered when the user enters the control. Can you not move your code there?

Answer (score 0):

You want the `Enter` event rather than `Load` then.  `Enter` fires when the user tabs onto, or clicks onto, the control and gives it focus.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your code in page load.....If you have update panel use updatepanel.update method